# Setting the package name of R.java independent of package attribute in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-manifest

I need to update the package name of my first Android app. To avoid changing the import in all my java classes, is there a way to specify the package name for the generated R.java file independent of the package name declared in the AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: The aapt tool has two options to do this --custom-package ( ver >= 2.1 ) and --rename-manifest-package.  http://java.dzone.com/articles/building-two-vesions-same.  Next step is to figure out the maven-android-plugin option to set these.

Comment: At present the maven-android-plugin does not support this feature. https://groups.google.com/d/topic/maven-android-developers/txaT6CK4Sgw/discussion

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no such way.